# Set alpha of legend in ggplot/Plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

How do I get the legend in a `plotly` plot to not inherit the alpha values used in a plot?

I know how to do this with ggplot2: `guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1)))` but this does not translate to plotly.

is there a similar option for `plotly`? When converting from `ggplot` to `plotly` it seems to pick up on the alpha value for the legend no matter what I do.

Example Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

D <- rbind(beaver1,beaver2)
D$beaver= c(rep('A',nrow(beaver1)),rep('B',nrow(beaver2)))

p <- ggplot(D,aes(x=time,y=temp,color=beaver,group=day))+
  geom_point(alpha=.1,show.legend = F)+
  geom_line(alpha=.1,show.legend = F)+
  geom_smooth(se=F)

ggplotly(p)
```

The ggplot version:

[image: ggplot version]

The plotly version:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot control the opacity of the legend.

If you look at the string output of `ggplotly` you can see that there are 2x3 traces. 3 traces for each beaver, one for the markers, one for the connecting line and one for the smooth line. The first trace determines the legend, so you could just rearrange your `ggplot` and it should work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

D <- rbind(beaver1,beaver2)
D$beaver= c(rep('A',nrow(beaver1)),rep('B',nrow(beaver2)))

p <- ggplot(D,aes(x=time,y=temp,color=beaver,group=day))+
  geom_smooth(se=F)+
  geom_point(alpha=.1,show.legend = F)+
  geom_line(alpha=.1,show.legend = F)


gp <- ggplotly(p)
gp
```

[image]

The other solution would be to turn on and off the legends.

```
gp$x$data[[1]]$showlegend <- FALSE
gp$x$data[[2]]$showlegend <- FALSE
gp$x$data[[5]]$showlegend <- TRUE
gp$x$data[[6]]$showlegend <- TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you. In this case the layer order does not matter, and it looks like your second solution could solve cases where the order does matter.